# Is possible get which component call some action Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vee-validate

Is possible to get which component call some action Vuex ?

I return a promise from vuex actions and take some decisions in component as set errors messages on respective fields but I would like to set on component.$validator.errors asap I receive http response (in action method)

Is that possible and a good approach ?

Comment: Can't you just resolve / reject with the appropriate errors? That way the component which initiated the call can take the decisions?

Comment: @IdsKlijnsma Maybe. But I think components doesn't have to see http responses (status, body, headers) but only take some action over any response object (error or success). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vuex when you make a call to a mutation or action you can send an object alongside your dispatch call, if you wanted to track the component which called an action you could also send that as part of the object. Better yet you could have all objects sent via Vuex extend a specific class if your using typescript. Though note that finding which component called an action or mutation is not native behavior for Vuex.

Consider the following:

```
try{
    let out = await this.$store.dispatch('someActionHandler', {referingComponent: this.$options.name, someParam:[1,2,3]})
} catch (e){
   // Lets deal with the problem
}
```

In here we are sending the name of the component as a parameter, so it can be checked inside our action handler or alternatively you could just pass this straight to a mutation, though I think the former is a more likely case if you plan to build logic into this.

As for if this is a good approach, the answer to that is fairly subjective, I personally don't see any problems with the above approach. Though I would think it was an anti pattern if the majority of components are never checked or the added data ends up becoming meaningless fluff passed alongside every call.

Comment: Understood. I agree about anti pattern if most of components doesn't have this behaviour, and that's my case. So, do you think the approach returning promises from vuex actions and make decisions in components (set error messages) is better approach ? Any sugestions ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to handle everything that involves a specific component inside of an action handler so you can resolve the promise and build each individual mutation separately.

Comment: Can't really suggest much more than just K.I.S.S principle as once you bring things back to local state inside of the component you can trivialize your store so everything is simpler to understand and comprehend. Also very worth separating your monolith store into multiple individual stores and abstracting component based actions to those if you have no relying state.

Comment: Dont return and resolve promises in components but in actions? How, for example, set error in specific component field by name ?

Comment: What I meant by that is we could dispatch the above and then resolve an error inside of the action handler, then where we made our call in the local state we would have a simple method that gets called if err != undefined or however you want to catch it which will deal with the result of the action locally.

Comment: I updated my answer to give a bit more of a hint, should be fairly obvious now. Let me know if you need more code to help :-).

Comment: Nice. I'll do that! More centralized I guess. Thanks for your help! Have a good day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176576/discussion-between-vitor-hugo-morales-and-li-x).